# How can I use ng-show based on two possible values of the same variable (OR expression)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code here :

```html
 <div class="columnscalc">
    <div class="choice-buttons-field equacao">
        <label class="phq9choice">Equação</label>
        <div id="crea" class="options-depress">
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.eq == 0 }" ng-click="calc.eq = 0"><span>Creatinina CKD-EPI</span></div>
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.eq == 1 }" ng-click="calc.eq = 1"><span>Cistatina C CKD-EPI</span></div>
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.eq == 3 }" ng-click="calc.eq = 3"><span>Creatinina-Cistatina C<br />CKD-EPI</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choice-buttons-field">
        <label>Sexo</label>
        <div class="options">
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.sex == 0}" ng-click="calc.sex = 0"><span>Masculino</span></div>
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.sex == 1 }" ng-click="calc.sex = 1"><span>Feminino</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choice-buttons-field no-hover">
        <label for="idade">Idade</label>
        <div id="ckdIdade" class="options no-hover">
            <input type="number" id="idade"
                   name="idade"
                   autofocus
                   onblur="mgrPlaceholderOnBlur(this);" onfocus="mgrPlaceholderOnFocus(this);" ng-model="calc.idade" />
            <div id="anosLabel"><span>Anos</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choice-buttons-field no-hover" ng-show="calc.eq == 0 || calq.eq == 3">
        <label for="creat">Creatinina sérica</label>
        <div id="ckdIdade" class="options">
            <input type="number" id="creat"
                   name="creat"
                   autofocus
                   placeholder="Norm: 62 - 115" ng-model="calc.creat" />
            <div id="unity" onclick="javascript: atualizarUnidade(this)"><span id="unidade">µmol/L</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choice-buttons-field no-hover" ng-show="calc.eq == 1 || calq.eq == 3">
        <label for="cist">Cistatina sérica C</label>
        <div id="ckdIdade" class="options no-hover">
            <input type="number" id="cist"
                   name="cist"
                   autofocus
                   placeholder="Norm: 0.51 - 0.98" ng-model="calc.cist" />
            <div id="anosLabel" ng-class="{'active' : calc.mg == -1 }"><span>mg/L</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="choice-buttons-field" ng-show="calc.eq == 0 || calq.eq == 3">
        <div class="optionalPreset raca">
            <label style="display:block">Raça</label>
            <p id="optionalNote">A raça pode/não pode fornecer melhores estimativas de TFG; Opcional</p>
        </div>
        <div id="racas" class="options">
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.raca == 0}" ng-click="calc.raca = 0"><span>Negra</span></div>
            <div ng-class="{'active' : calc.raca == 1 }" ng-click="calc.raca = 1"><span>Não-negra</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I have the 3 initial divs that when clicked fill the variable calc.eq.
Then I want the next divs to be shown or hidden based on the value of that variable, the problem is that I use an OR condition and it seems the app only recognizes the first parcel

(e.g.: calc.eq == 1 || calc.eq == 3, the app only shows the div when calc.eq = 1 not when calc.eq = 3, but if I change the order calc.eq == 3 || calc.eq == 1 the app only shows the div when calc.eq = 3)

What is wrong with my code? How can I rearrange it so the divs are shown based on both parcels of the OR condition and not only the first one?

Comment: In Angular dont' exist `ng-show` -ng-show is about AngularJs- you can use `*ngIf=(condition)` or `[style.display]="(!condition)?'none':null"` -*ngIf remove from the DOM, change the style.display only change the display. See that using style.display in this way, if condition don't add the style in your html element

Comment: Does your code have a typo: `calq.eq == 3` instead of `calc.eq == 3` ??